# ASP.NET authentication to external server with client credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, authentication

I have a site (ASP.NET) and this will be an Intranet only site.

Users will connect and be able to upload and edit images and then the image will be saved to a sharepoint Library with their username as the creator.

Right now, it looks like I can't use the user credentials to connect to SharePoint, and it uses the service account, which isn't allowed to the library, and kicks back a 401 error.

Without having to have the user put their credentials on the page, what can I do to authenticate using integrated windows credentials?

Comment: Impersonation should be what you are looking for http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158#3 It will allow you to impersonate a specific account, or the currently authenticated user.

Comment: I'm still getting a 401 error, but I'm going to see if it's for a different reason. I'll get back to you.